# Get different image file formats in JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, image, variables, file-type

I'm developing my own portfolio website, which is based on JavaScript gallery. The script shows and prealoads images by tracking current position and it works brilliant when it comes to load only one filetype. Here comes extract:

```
var $current = 1;
var $sourceImage = 'path-to-images/'+$current+'.jpg';
var $newImage = new Image();
$newImage.src = $sourceImage;
```

But what if in the directory there are more than one filetype, for example: 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.gif 4.png ... ? What's the best way to find extension of file that exists on server and pass it to the variable?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Which javascript gallery are you using?

Comment: It's my own complex script, written to fit my specific needs. In my question I included only part that relates to my problem, I just need to know how to include proper extension in $sourceImage variable :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if a file exists with JavaScript you have to send an ajax request:

```
var req = this.window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") : new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (!req) {
        throw new Error('XMLHttpRequest not supported');
    }

    // HEAD Results are usually shorter (faster) than GET
    req.open('HEAD', url, false);
    req.send(null);
    if (req.status == 200) {
        console.log('file exists');
    }
    else {
        console.log('file does not exist');
    }
```

from [phpjs](http://phpjs.org/functions/file_exists:399).

Comment: So to use your solution I need to pass every possibility in var req? First check *.jpg availability, if not found check the *.gif and so on?

Comment: Yep, so you should change your solution to use Aldehir's one ^^

Comment: works brilliant! thank you both, in near future I'll rewrite entire script to use Aldehir's solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your solutions are limited when only using Javascript. The simplest way is to have an array containing all of the file names,

```
var imageFiles = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.gif", "4.png"];
```

However, this may be undesirable if there are a large number of images.

Alternatively, you can write a page in PHP (or any language of your choice) that returns all the images in the directory as a JSON array.

```
["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.gif", "4.png"]
```

Then just use a framework such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to request the page; [getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) would work nicely in this case. You can always reinvent the wheel, but I highly suggest a framework for AJAX.